# Resolving ORA-04063 After Enforcing Noneditionable Types

Tags: oracle, ora-04063

Here is the translation from Lithuanian to English:

I applied the `FORCE` option with the command:

```sql
ALTER USER IPR ENABLE EDITIONS FORCE;
```

I did this because Oracle did not allow me to execute the command due to the following error:

Error report -
ORA-38819: user IPR owns one or more objects whose type is editionable and that have noneditioned dependent objects
38819. 00000 - "user %s owns one or more objects whose type is editionable and that have noneditioned dependent objects"
*Cause: An attempt was made to violate the rule "A noneditioned object may not depend on an editioned object."
*Action: Either make sure that those objects owned by this user whose type is editionable have no noneditioned dependent objects; or use the FORCE option.

But now a problem has arisen.

There is a table with a field like this:
`"TG_VISIBILITIES" "IPR"."VARCHAR_ARRAY" NOT NULL ENABLE,`

where the type `"IPR"."VARCHAR_ARRAY"` was:

```sql
create or replace EDITIONABLE TYPE "VARCHAR_ARRAY" AS VARYING ARRAY (2000) OF VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Since the table is `NONEDITIONABLE` and the type assigned to its field was `EDITIONABLE`, Oracle may have invalidated the table.
That is, it does not allow anything to be done with it at all, not even to select from it:

ORA-04063: table "IPR.TVARKARASCIU_GENERAVIMAI" has errors
04063. 00000 - "%s has errors"
*Cause: Attempt to execute a stored procedure or use a view that has errors. For stored procedures, the problem could be syntax errors or references to other, non-existent procedures. For views, the problem could be a reference in the view's defining query to a non-existent table. Can also be a table which has references to non-existent or inaccessible types.
*Action: Fix the errors and/or create referenced objects as necessary.
Error at Line: 15 Column: 19

I dropped that type and created it anew as `NONEDITIONABLE`:

```sql
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE "VARCHAR_ARRAY" AS VARYING ARRAY (2000) OF VARCHAR2(4000)
```

However, this did not help. It throws the same error again. It feels like the table DDL "does not see" the newly created type `VARCHAR_ARRAY` for it.

The `ALTER TABLE` command also does not work. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/type-dependencies.html#GUID-DE251FEC-8F11-46E3-B696-05A15D35F8FB) says you can't modify a Type that is used in a Table. If you don't need to preserve the data in the table then just drop the table and re-create it. If you need to preserve the data I think you will need to temporarily add a new column and shuffle the data around while you drop the original column, drop the original type, re-create the type, then re-add the original column, and then restore the data. However, if your table is already in an unreadable state, you will first need to restore the table from a backup.

The following is an example of this process to modify a Varchar2 Varray Type (extending the Varchar2 length) used in a table:

```
create  TYPE VARCHAR_ARRAY AS VARYING ARRAY (2) OF VARCHAR2(10) ; 
/

create table t1 (TG_VISIBILITIES VARCHAR_ARRAY NOT NULL ENABLE);

insert into t1 values (VARCHAR_ARRAY('abc','cde'));

-- attempt modifying type fails:  ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents 
create or replace TYPE VARCHAR_ARRAY AS VARYING ARRAY (2) OF VARCHAR2(20) ; 
/

--temporarily create new type to shuffle data 
create TYPE VARCHAR_ARRAY_2 AS VARYING ARRAY (2) OF VARCHAR2(10) ; 
/

alter table t1 add TG_VISIBILITIES_2  VARCHAR_ARRAY_2;

alter table t1 modify TG_VISIBILITIES null;

update t1 set TG_VISIBILITIES_2 = cast(TG_VISIBILITIES as VARCHAR_ARRAY_2), TG_VISIBILITIES = null;

drop type VARCHAR_ARRAY validate;

alter table t1 drop column TG_VISIBILITIES;

--re-create original type but with modified  
create TYPE VARCHAR_ARRAY AS VARYING ARRAY (2) OF VARCHAR2(20) ; 
/

alter table t1 add TG_VISIBILITIES  VARCHAR_ARRAY;

update t1 set TG_VISIBILITIES = cast(TG_VISIBILITIES_2  as VARCHAR_ARRAY);

alter table t1 drop column TG_VISIBILITIES_2;

drop type VARCHAR_ARRAY_2;

select * from t1;
```